# Which Android Priority Job Queue (Asynk Task, Multithreading) library would you recommend for Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-safety

Which Android Priority Job Queue (Job Manager)  library would you recommend for Android?

now i am using greenrobot/EventBus
but EventBus functionality is too narrow(EventBus is publish/subscribe event bus)

alternatives:

1. https://github.com/Arasthel/AsyncJobLibrary
2. https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice
3. https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue
4. https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android

What do you recommend?

Job Manager will take care of prioritization, persistence, load balancing, delaying, network control, grouping etc. It also provides a nice lifecycle for your jobs to provide a better, consistent user experience.

Comment: As voted, this question is indeed off-topic.
I don't want to encourage off-topic questions, but hopefully this will help anyway:

I dont' have experience with the others, but am using android-priority-jobqueue - it is working well for me, and I believe that it offers all of the features that you mentioned.

Comment: thanks, looks like it was no longer being developed, but i try it

Comment: @user3871754 It is now currently being maintained by Yigit at https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue